# Achieving transactionality with huge data in Apache Nifi custom processor for Azure Data Explorer

Tags: apache-spark, etl, apache-nifi, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

We are developing a custom processor in Apache Nifi for ingesting data into Azure Data Explorer. What we want to achieve is transactionality during data ingestion. The source of the processor can be TBs of telemetry data as well as CDC logs. What that means is in case of any failure while ingesting data of particular partition to ADX,we will delete/cleanup any other ingested data of other partitions. Since Azure Data Explorer is an append only database, unfortunately we cant perform delete on the ingested data of same partition or other partition. So to achieve this kind of transactionality of large ingested data, we are thinking to implement something similar we have done for Apache Spark ADX connector. We will be creating temporary tables inside Azure Data Explorer before ingesting to the actual tables. The worker nodes in apache spark will create these temporary tables and report the ingestion status to the driver node. The driver node on receiving the success status of all the worker nodes performs ingestion on the actual table or else the ingestion is aborted along with cleanup of temporary table. So basically we aggregate the worker node task status in the driver node in spark to take further decision on whether to ingest data into ADX table or not.
Question 1: Is this possible in Apache Nifi follows a zero master cluster strategy as opposed to master-slave architecture of apache spark?
Question 2: In our custom processor in Nifi, is it possible to run custom code of a particular partition say the cluster coordinator node. Also is it possible to get the details of the partition inside the processor?
Question 3: Is it possible to get the details of tasks executed at the various partitions and take decisions based on the task status. Can all these be done inside the same processor.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. May I suggest a direct communication with the ADX product group?

Comment: Hi David, I am from Kusto Dev team working on Apache Nifi connector for Kusto.

Comment: Oh... It was a nifi question 